# Can someone in Europe redeem a Minecraft gift card purchased in America?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend's Microsoft account recently got hacked and he now needs to repurchase Minecraft Java Edition. I was looking to gift him a Minecraft Java gift card but he is in Europe and I am in the United States, will it affect the purchase at all?

Answer (score 1):

There's no region-locking on Minecraft gift cards. All he needs is a Microsoft account, and he'll be able to redeem the code anywhere in the world at https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/redeem. (and no, the /en-us/ on this is not important)